# How to write numbers in boldface type using LaTeX Beamer

Tags: boldmath

I want to write a vector $1_n$ in bold face where all its entries are one. I have tried all of the following, but it will not work. I even included \userpackage{bm}. But not working. Any help, please?

```
$\bm{1}_n$\\
$\boldsymbol{1}_n$\\
$\mathbf{1}_n$\\
$\textbf{1}_n$
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Rarther than posting code snipptes like this please give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). In particular, the code should compile. This said, in what sense do these not work? All of these lines result in a bold-faced `1` for me. In this case, the recommended approach is to use `$\mathbf{1}_n$`.

Comment: `$\textbf{1}$` works fine for me, the others don't result in boldface.

Comment: What fonts are you using in Beamer? It’s possible you selected a font theme without bold math.

Comment: I had the same problem, which was solved by removing `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` from my preamble. I guess `bm` and `fontenc` don't get along well.

Answer (score 0):

I used package `\usepackage{amsbsy}` and I wrote it as `\pmb{1}_n`. It works fine for me now.

Comment: This is only a "last resort" solution for when you have no bold font, it is not real bold, just three 1 overprinting, the forms in the question would produce real bold unless you have code not shown choosing a non standard font set that has no bold font.

Comment: Don't use `\pmb` unless you have any other method to get bold symbols. Try methods that @Zarko gave. If that didn't work, you have to give a minimal working example to tell us what you write.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear, what is your problem. More certain we can be, if you would provide an MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document. As example of it with your code fragment is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Comparison of normal and boldface math variables}
\verb+\bm+:\qquad          $1_n, \bm{1}_n$\\
\verb+\boldsymbol+:\qquad  $1_n, \boldsymbol{1}_n$\\
\verb+\mathbf+:\qquad      $1_n, \mathbf{1}_n$\\
%$\textbf{1}_n$ this should not be used 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which gives expected result:

[image]